# Google Sheets Lookup values 2d

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to find a formula to solve my problem.

I have the table below in Google Sheets.
[image]

6, 7, 8 at the very top is the age of a child.
Let's say I want to lookup value 1,0 for a child age of 8 in for "ΣΚσπ" (sorry for Greek, it is the 2nd column below 8). I want to lookup from the bottom up and find the FIRST value that is less or equal 1,0.
I should lookup the result is column A.
The correct result in this case is ≤5.

Could you please help me using the correct formula for this?

Thanks!

Update:
I have created a help sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aarl_lUMAQoXLdsmBMVeWBTk2_M75Oy4aH-WPJX-V1Q/edit?usp=sharing

In M14 of the help sheet there is a function that gives the correct result for me (it is not completed), but it is not the best way at all.
I will have to use Importrange and the formula would end up pretty cluttered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may test:*

```js
=xlookup(1;filter(B3:P10;B2:P2=M16;scan(;B1:P1;lambda(a;c;if(c="";a;c)))=L16);A3:A10;;-1;-1)
```

[image]

Comment: I have really no words to thank you about your help! It works absolutely correct!